# how to preform a distinct on a column in the middle of the query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a (distinct) or anything else that would do the same thing on the country column but it's not working this is the where I got stuck

```
with t1 as(select   c.customerid cnumber ,  c.firstname fn, c.lastname ln ,   i.billingcountry country  , sum(i.total) tot   from 

Invoice I join Customer c on 

i.CustomerId=c.CustomerId

group by 1,2,3,4
order by 4)

select distinct cnumber, fn, ln, country, max( tot) from t1
group by 1,2,3,4
order by 4;
```

Comment: Do you mean `distinct country`?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: What do your results look like now and how do you want them to look?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: @GordonLinoff  this is a part of what i've got from my query 
56 Diego Gutiérrez Argentina 37.62
55 Mark Taylor Australia 37.62
7 Astrid Gruber Austria 42.62
8 Daan Peeters Belgium 37.62
1 Luís Gonçalves Brazil 39.62
10 Eduardo Martins Brazil 37.62
11 Alexandre Rocha Brazil 37.62
12 Roberto Almeida Brazil 37.62
13 Fernanda Ramos Brazil 37.62
3 François Tremblay Canada 39.62
14 Mark Philips Canada 37.62

and this is what it should look like

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to apply distinct on all 4 columns, where they are already in DISTINCT mode as you applied GROUP BY on that same 4 columns. There is nothing going to change in the output come from table T1 if you apply further DISTINCT on rows from that table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for a good SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT c.Country, SUM(i.Total) TotalSpent, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.CustomerId
    FROM 
        Customer c
        JOIN Invoice i ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
    GROUP BY c.CustomerId
)

SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
JOIN(
    SELECT Country, MAX(TotalSpent) AS MaxTotalSpent, FirstName, LastName, CustomerId
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY Country
)t2
ON t1.Country = t2.Country
WHERE t1.TotalSpent = t2.MaxTotalSpent
ORDER BY Country;
```